# Java reading text in a data file, and saving it as a variable

Tags: java

I am a student, and need help doing an assignment in my Java class.

We have to use Java to read a .TXT file, and then use the letters inside of it to create percentages of chances.

We were given a file with tons of BG, GG, BB, etc. The point is to take part of it, and then get Java to calculate the odds of it being BB (Boy Boy), GB (Girl Boy), etc.

This is what I have, and I know that all is does now is read and print the file.

What would I add to it to make it do what I need?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Family
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
      throws IOException
  {
    String breakLoop;
    File file = new File("MaleFemaleInFamily.txt");
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);

    while (inFile.hasNext())
    {
      breakLoop = inFile.next();
      System.out.println(breakLoop);
    }
    inFile.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is JavaScript here?

Comment: Could you please provide the input TXT file or at least a few lines of these? Otherwise it is hard to guess what "to make it do what I need" means.

Comment: @DimaSan where is Trey speaking about JS?

Comment: in the question tag.

Comment: Agree with first question, we need to know the format of the input file.  Is it just a single line with letter pairs such as, ie, a space-delimited file, like: "BB GB GG GB BB BB" etc. or is it a new line-delimited file with the BB, GB, GG, etc. each on separate lines?  I can pretty much guess what the point of the exercise is: 1) How to read in a .txt file and 2) How to parse out the values in it.  Hint: You will probably need to use the StringTokenizer class in the java.util package.

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
 package NewFile_files;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.Scanner;



    public class OddsCalculator {
        long bgCount;
        long ggCount;
        long bbCount;
        // set this variable's value, as the number of lines after which you want to
        // calculate odds.
        int startShowingOddsAfter = 15;

        void calculator() throws FileNotFoundException {
            String breakLoop;
            File file = new File("MaleFemaleInFamily.txt");
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);
            int i = 0;
            while (inFile.hasNext()) {
                breakLoop = inFile.next();
                System.out.println(breakLoop);
                switch (breakLoop.toLowerCase()) {
                case "bb":
                    bbCount++;
                    break;
                case "bg":
                    bgCount++;
                    break;
                case "gg":
                    ggCount++;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                if (i++ > 15)
                    oddsPrinter();

            }
            inFile.close();
        }

        private void oddsPrinter() {
            System.out.println("Odds for next word are :");
            long total = bbCount + bgCount + ggCount;
            System.out.println("To be BB : " + (bbCount * 100) / total + "%");
            System.out.println("To be BG : " + (bgCount * 100) / total + "%");
            System.out.println("To be GG : " + (ggCount * 100) / total + "%");

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
            new OddsCalculator().calculator();
        }
    }
    **strong text**
```